# clicking on dots on UIPageControl doesn't change page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uipagecontrol

So I just changed the PageControl project from Apple's site [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html). The issue is that clicking on the dots doesn't seem to change the page. What is wrong with that code?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code downloaded `- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender`
seems working pretty good, but as the comment says *"load the visible page and the page on either side of it", it's not working at "1" and "6".*

Comment: I understand that.. but I am saying if I click on the dots next to the current page, it should go to the next page or vice versa for previous.. but it is not doing so

Comment: shame that I never used Nib myself... what I could conclude from the codes: wherever `- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender` is linked to the UIPageControl, the sender's currentPage is not sync with real currentPage. any click between 1 and 4 works well (real numbers 2-5 ), but if it's an *edge* page, like 1, the sender can only recognise the page 0 before 1,the same with page 5 after page 4.